# Mutual information with a Dirac delta type pdf

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, dirac-delta

What does the $MI(X,Y)$ convey about $Y$, when one of the probability distributions, $X$ is trivial and has all the probability concentrated at a single point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are discrete and define the probability functions
$$p_X(x)=P\{X=x\}\, ,$$ 
$$p_Y(y)=P\{Y=y\}\, ,$$
$$p_{X,Y}(x,y)=P\{X=x,Y=y\}\, .$$

You are assuming that $p_X(x_0)=1$, for some $x_0$. By total probability, we have
$$p_Y(y)=\sum_x p_{X,Y}(x,y)=p_{X,Y}(x_0,y)\, .$$

Hence, the mutual information is
$$I(X,Y)=\sum_y\sum_x p_{X,Y}(x,y) \log\left( \frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_X(x)p_Y(y)} \right) \, = \sum_yp_{X,Y}(x_0,y) \log\left( \frac{p_{X,Y}(x_0,y)}{p_X(x_0)p_Y(y)} \right)$$
$$=\sum_y \bigg(p_Y(y)\log(1)\bigg)=0\, .$$

Answer (score 2):

Nothing! If $X$ is trivial, then by definition $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the mutual information is zero, regardless of $Y$.

Comment: Indeed, to see it more directly, note that for this $X$, then the joint probability must factor as $P(X=x,Y=y) = P(Y=y)$ if $X=\hat{x}$ for the singleton $\hat{x}$ receiving all the probability mass, and zero otherwise, which is the same as $P(X=x,Y=y) = P(X=x)P(Y=y)$. Plugging this into the formula for MI you'll see it's zero. More intuitively, the mutual information between any random object $Y$ and any deterministic object $X$ needs to be 0 .. how can a deterministic quantity tell you something about the entropy of $Y$?